# Ещё один случай употребления родительного падежа с конкретным объектом при отрицании

Tags: падежи, родительный-или-винительный

*«Виват, гардемарины!», Бестужев (играет Евстигнеев):*

> Я знаю, что вы везёте с Беловым пакет в Цербст. Я не буду требовать у вас ***этого пакета***, кто ж возьмёт на себя смелость ломать печать государыни!

Никто не возражает против такого употребления?

Вижу, что нет интереса к этому вопросу. Действительно, у меня нет вопроса как такового, но меня интересуют любые мысли по поводу этого примера.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я не возражаю. Речь в "Гардемаринах" идёт о событиях 18 века, а прежде при глаголах с отрицанием почти всегда употреблялся родительный падеж. «Русская грамматика» пишет:

> «**Единая старая норма обязательного родительного падежа при глаголах с
>   отрицанием** в современном языке под влиянием разговорной речи не
>   выдерживается: во многих случаях употребление винительного падежа не
>   только предпочитается, но и является единственно правильным».

http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters?id=67

Строго говоря, правила, устанавливающего употребление после переходных глаголов **исключительно винительного падежа,** нет. Всё зависит от контекста и интонации. 
**Факультативное употребление родительного и винительного падежа при переходном глаголе с отрицанием связано со стилистическим различием:** конструкции с родительным падежом характерны для книжной речи, конструкции с ВИНИТЕЛЬНЫМ падежом – для речи РАЗГОВОРНОЙ: *Я не умаляю чьих-либо заслуг.*
https://pravopisanie_i_stilistika.academic.ru/202/%D0%9F%D0%B

В нашем примере **родительный падеж применён для стилизации под старину.**

Comment: Спасибо, Людмила! А зачем Вы исказили фразу (там "не намерен умалять")? *...Прежде при глаголах с отрицанием почти всегда употреблялся родительный падеж* — вот! Пытался в этом убедить оледа, но не получилось.

Comment: Артём, искажения я даже не заметила, видимо, писала на автомате и сократила случайно, да и вижу плохо...

Comment: По ссылке можно было просто скопировать, там: "Я не намерен умалять чьих-либо заслуг…"